# How to add spacing between two span elements

Tags: css, html

I have two span elements. I want them to sit side-by-side and contain some text. Is this possible? If so what am I doing wrong?

```
.added-box{
 background-color:#06C;
 padding:8px;
 margin:8px;
}

.edited-box{
 background-color:#093;
 padding:8px;
 margin:8px;

}
```

And the page code is:

```
<p align="right">
   <span class="edited-box">sfds<span>
   <span class="added-box">sfds<span>
</p>
```

Edit: What I am hoping to get is a box, somewhat like the one on this page which has my name, time I asked the question and my points. I don't mind how I get it, but css is preferred, it looks like StackOverflow is using a table. Is this the only way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two typos in your HTML where you are failing to close the `<span>` tags with `</span>`. It should be:

```
<p align="right">
  <span class="edited-box">sfds</span>
  <span class="added-box">sfds</span>
</p>
```

This typo is causing your `edited-box` class to wrap everything and therefore the CSS is breaking.

Answer (score -4):

Use `&nbsp;` for space between spans.

Comment: Isn't that a bit inelegant ... not saying I am right ... just asking.

Comment: The other problem is that it seems the first span contains the second - based on the coloring ... I tried &nbsp it doesn't stop this problem, so there is some green on the right hand side of the blue.

Comment: Non-breaking space should not be used for creating horizontal space. Non-breaking space should be used as a white space character in places where a line break might be confusing, e.g. within a number 1&nbsp;000&nbsp;000 dollars.